# How to attach database mdf file to SQL Server Express without Management Studio?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express

Currently I am working on a C# Windows application, and this application is using SQL Server Express.

I have installed SQL Server and the Management Studio on my PC.

I have installed SQL Server Express on the client's PC, but I don't want to install Management Studio as well.

How do I attach my `.mdf` and `.ldf` files to SQL Server Express, without having SQL Server Management Studio installed?

This is my connection string

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=password;Connect Timeout=0
```

Comment: Use a service-based database instead by adding it as a new item to your project.

Comment: I don't understand S.Akbari, can u describe briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `AttachDBFileName` parameter in your connection string and point it to your MDF file.  There is a special value you can put into this to refer to a local data directory so that you don't need to use a hardcoded path:

```
AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf
```

For ASP.NET applications, the `|DataDirectory|` refers to the `App_Data` folder under your project.  I'm not sure what it refers to for a windows app, but I'm guessing you could figure it out pretty easily.

Note that `InitialCatalog` is not necessary when using `AttachDBFileName`.  `InitialCatalog` is normally used to refer to a DB that the SQL Server instance already knows about.  `AttachDBFileName` is used to instantiate a database from a given file.

Comment: After adding AttachFileName in connection string, where should I put my MDF and LDF file while publishing or building?

Comment: @Yash AttachDBFileName takes a relative path from your exe, so to build you'll probably need to copy the MDF to the output directory as appropriate (this can be done as part of the build).  You'll also have to configure the same for publishing.